# Struggling to align form elements

Tags: html, css, forms

I've been trying to get my form elements to align for ages and tried restarting multiple times, but it's just not working with me. This is what I'm trying to get:

[image: Ideal form]

This is what I get:

[image: Bad form]

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2pg8fh75/)

My main problem is probably the radio buttons,  which I can't get text to the right of when they're floated right, and for some reason can't get to float left without floating everything left.
 I am really new to HTML, so I might just be missing something obvious?

```css
.container {
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  line-height: 3;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container input {
  width: 700px;
  float: right;
}

.container select {
  width: 400px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <form action="user data.php">
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="First Name"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="Last Name"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="e-mail Address"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="cell" value="Cell Number"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="ID/Passport Number"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="dob" value="Date of Birth"> <br>

    <label for="course">Course:</label>
    <select name="course"></select> <br>

    <label for="hlevel">Highest Education Level:</label>
    <select name="hlevel"></select> <br>

    <p>Identification Type:</p>

    <input type="radio" name="idtype" id="passnum" style="width: 5px;" value="Passport Number">
    <label for="passnum"> Passport Number </label> <br>

    <input type="radio" name="idtype" id="idnum" value="ID Number">
    <label for="idnum"> ID Number </label> <br>

    <label for="gender">Gender:</label>


    <label for="pgroup">Population Group:</label>
    <select name="pgroup"></select> <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit Info">
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you in a fixed-width site scenario? Those rigid margins and container widths aren't really a modern way to go about this. As soon as the screen drops below ~1300px it overflows.

Comment: @isherwood Fixed-width site? (really new to html)  But yes I would prefer to move away from that sort of thing (been getting annoyed with the navbar overflowing), it's just all I know >.<

Comment: You should look over any of the modern layout grid libraries (Bootstrap) for concept ideas, as well as flexbox and CSS grid. You're reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely plan on using these. ^^ Unfortunately, I'm learning this for my studies and I don't think they want me to use external libraries yet.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you use them. Just learn from them.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks. Your input along with a pretty beginner level video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8ZMzN40q0g) helped me out. Seems my main problems were floating some elements left and some right, unspecified label widths, and, of course, overly specific size measures. (Also, how do I close a question, as I'm pretty much done >.< )

Comment: Good to hear. Either provide and accept an answer or delete the question if it has no value to the community.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, add class to submit button

```
<input class="submit-btn" type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit Info">
```

In CSS, add below

```
form {
    max-width: 700px;
}
input {
    max-width: 700px;
}
.submit-btn {
    max-width: 80px;
}
```